# Python script creation, intersection Points and polygons

Tags: pyqgis, intersection

I have these two shapefiles, one with polygon geometry and the other with point geometry, that I am working on in QGIS. I want to create a script using Python to see the intersection of points and polygons, and where there is an intersection fill in the value of a field I created.

Psuedo code for this would be something like

```
for polygon in Aveiro_Polygon.features():
    for point in Aveiro.features():
        if point is contained within polygon:               
            point.setAttribute(someValue)
```

[image: Shps Point and Polygon]
[image: Table Of point]

Comment: what you are looking for is called "spatial join"